# Neither gzip nor deflate compression doesn't work for Apache server using mod_deflate or AddOutputFilterByType

Tags: apache, .htaccess, svg, compression, gzip

I'm trying to compress SVG files on my server, but whatever code i put in .htaccess it doesn't work!

This is my .htaccess code:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Proper MIME type for all files
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# JavaScript
#   Normalize to standard type (it's sniffed in IE anyways)
#   tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4329#section-7.2
AddType application/javascript         js jsonp
AddType application/json               json

# Audio
AddType audio/ogg                      oga ogg
AddType audio/mp4                      m4a f4a f4b

# Video
AddType video/ogg                      ogv
AddType video/mp4                      mp4 m4v f4v f4p
AddType video/webm                     webm
AddType video/x-flv                    flv

# SVG
#   Required for svg webfonts on iPad
#   twitter.com/FontSquirrel/status/14855840545
AddType     image/svg+xml              svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip                       svgz

# Webfonts
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject  eot
AddType application/x-font-ttf         ttf ttc
AddType font/opentype                  otf
AddType application/x-font-woff        woff

# Assorted types
AddType image/x-icon                        ico
AddType image/webp                          webp
AddType text/cache-manifest                 appcache manifest
AddType text/x-component                    htc
AddType application/xml                     rss atom xml rdf
AddType application/x-chrome-extension      crx
AddType application/x-opera-extension       oex
AddType application/x-xpinstall             xpi
AddType application/octet-stream            safariextz
AddType application/x-web-app-manifest+json webapp
AddType text/x-vcard                        vcf
AddType application/x-shockwave-flash       swf
AddType text/vtt                            vtt


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Gzip compression
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

<Location />
  # Insert filter
  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

  # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4         gzip-only-text/html

  # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

  # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE             !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  # Don't compress images
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

  # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
  Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</Location>


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Gzip compression
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

  # Force deflate for mangled headers developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping/
  <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
      RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>

  # Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
  <IfModule mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                  application/javascript \
                                  application/json \
                                  application/rss+xml \
                                  application/xhtml+xml \
                                  application/xml \
                                  application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                  application/x-font-ttf \
                                  font/opentype \
                                  image/x-icon \
                                  image/svg+xml \
                                  text/css \
                                  text/html \
                                  text/plain \
                                  text/x-component \
                                  text/xml
  </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

When I look at the response headers of my SVG files, it appears there is no GZip compression. 
It happens the same when I analyze the page via Google PageSpeed Insights.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does gzip work for any other kind of file type?

Comment: Yes, it does. I noticed also that appending "Vary: Accept-Encoding" (only to svg files) fails too. I'm wondering why...

Comment: I have done further testing and I discovered that every single image/whatever file is not gzipped. I have not figured out yet what is wrong. Last but not least my hosting provider tells me nothing useful...

Comment: @OpaleGR there is no point in gzipping some kind of files like jpg.

Comment: Yes, there is no point in gzipping jpg files, but I really need to gzip both image/svg+xml and image/x-icon because the score of my website on WebpageTest and Google Pagespeed Insights is influenced by this kind of compression.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `deflate` module, since the `gzip` module is not part of the standard Apache installation.

Add the following to use mod_deflate:

```
<filesMatch "\.(svg|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf|js|css|html)$">
 Header set Content-Encoding compress
 # Header set Content-Encoding x-compress 
</filesMatch>
```

[mod_gzip](http://mod-gzip.sourceforge.net/) is a standalone project.

> When responding with an encoding Apache will use whatever form (i.e., x-foo or foo) the client requested. If the client didn't specifically request a particular form Apache will use the form given by the AddEncoding directive. To make this long story short, you should always use x-gzip and x-compress for these two specific encodings. More recent encodings, such as deflate, should be specified without the x-.

**References**

- [How to check if my shared hosting provider has mod_gzip installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121211/1113772)
- [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_deflate.html)
- [Header Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_headers.html#header)
- [Content Negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/content-negotiation.html)
- [The Accept Encoding Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation#The_Accept-Encoding.3A_header)
- [Content-Encoding != Content-Type](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wndp/archive/2006/08/21/content-encoding-not-equal-content-type.aspx)
- [mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_negotiation.html)
- [mod_mime](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_mime.html#addencoding)
- [Apache Compile How-to](https://www.linux.com/learn/docs/ldp/424-apache-compile-howto)

Comment: I have just tried your code, but it doesn't work. I'll try to give you more informations: now I am using Apache + cPanel with the "Optimize Website" instrument that should successfully compress even my gzip files, but... it doesn't work (only with image/svg+xml and image/x-icon). I think it is fault of the server.

Comment: Comment out the `<IfModule>` statements for now. Add `AddEncoding deflate .svgz` or `AddEncoding x-gzip .svgz` to the beginning of the file as well.

Comment: I've updated the answer to `compress` and `x-compress` instead of `x-deflate`, which should work if all else fails.

Comment: I've just tried both `compress` and `x-compress`and... no result. I also discovered my website is not the only one affected by the problem: I tried to gzip compress svg files in other websites (hosted by the same service), but they have the same problem. So I decided to contact my (shared) hosting provider (for the forth time in six months!) asking them to explain me why do I have this problem. I think this problem is caused by some kind of configuration I can't touch because I've not the privileges (shared hosting)

Comment: Are your files in the same directory as your .htaccess file? If not, try copying it to the same directory.

Comment: They are in different directories, but I have already tried to move them to the root of my site and the result was the same. After a long waiting time, my hosting provider told me that "they are verifying whether .svg and .ico files can be compress or not". So I'm waiting for them. Thank you for helping me in this endless nightmare.

Comment: End of the story: they "activated" the compression, but "magically" it works only **partially**. On WebPageTest the  "Compress Transfer" value increased from F to C. I just think I can't do anything else because of the **limitations imposed by my own server** at this time.

Comment: @OpaleGR Facing the exact same issue. SVG files don't get compressed, while other file types do.  By any chance, did you find a fix for this?